# Sonar cyclic dependency issue

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube-4.0

I'm getting from Sonar a lot of these violations, but I think they are not really cycles.

So for example I have:

**de.codeplumber.core.abc.core.Holder.java

de.codeplumber.core.xyz.core.User.java**

The Holder.java uses User.java as one of the properties and has getter and setter for getting and setting the User object. Below is the code for Holder.java

```
private User user = new User();
public User getUser() {
    return user ;
}
public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

Now Sonar is reporting the violation in Holder.java

**Remove the dependency on the source file "de/codeplumber/core/xyz/core/User.java" to break a package cycle.**

There is no reverse dependency on the package to Holder.java from the package of User.java.

I am not understanding why sonar reports this issue. Previously I had the cyclic dependency in some other classes and i fixed it as there were direct cyclic dependency.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please share the relevant code for both classes, if you only show one side of the suspected cycle, we can't tell if there is one at all.

Comment: There are few other getter setter which return/string in Holder.java and Name is just another value object class with getter and setter without any back reference to Holder.java package. I saw some other reference post in sonar site and there too there is no clear reply from them  http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/squid-Avoid-cycle-between-java-packages-td5017551.html